# List is getting reset although it has been saved

Tags: c#, arraylist

My job right now is to create a Recipe Book. The Recipe class has name and list of Ingredient(Zutaten) as properties. When I create a recipe for the 1st time and save it in a List of recipe, it has the correct data. 
1) Why as i entered my 2nd code part below to create 2nd recipe, the 1st recipe List of Ingredient(Zutaten) is emptied? (I didn't do anything to alter the recipe data)
2) Why as i save the 2nd recipe in the List of recipe, the 1st recipe has the same List of Ingredient of the 2nd Recipe?

```
  public Rezept(String name, List<Zutaten> ingredient)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.ingredient = ingredient;
            }
```

this is 1 of my class Rezept.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Verwaltung ve = new Verwaltung();
        private List<Rezept> rezept = new List<Rezept>();   
        List<Zutaten> z = new List<Zutaten>();

        String na;
        Zutaten zutat;
        int m;

             private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {

            z.Clear();

                na = tBName.Text;
                m = Convert.ToInt32(tBMenge.Text);
                switch (comboBoxUnit.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    case ("Gramm"):
                        zutat = new Zutaten(na, m, Einheit.Gramm);
                        break;
                    case "Litre":
                        zutat = new Zutaten(na, m, Einheit.Litre);
                        break;
                    case "Stueck":
                        zutat = new Zutaten(na, m, Einheit.Stueck);
                        break;
                }
                z.Add(zutat);

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Text = na;
                item.SubItems.Add(m.ToString());
                switch (zutat.getEinheit)
                {
                    case Einheit.Gramm:
                        item.SubItems.Add("Gramm");
                        break;
                    case Einheit.Litre:
                        item.SubItems.Add("Litre");
                        break;
                    case Einheit.Stueck:
                        item.SubItems.Add("Stueck");
                        break;
                }

                lVZutaten.Items.Add(item);

}
```

and this is how i create a new list of Zutaten everytime. And to create a new Rezept is, i used this method

```
Rezept r = new Rezept(textBoxName.Text, z);
                rezept.Add(r);
```

z is the List of the Zutaten that i have created in 2nd code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the same list in both instances.

You have a single list.  A reference to that list is saved in each recipe.  Each time you click add, it clears out the list and adds a new item.

According to your comment, you have 2 buttons, one to add an ingredient, and one to finish the recipe.  You should never be clearing out (removing) an ingredient list.  You should create a new list whenever you create the Recipe.

```
private List<Rezept> recipes = new List<Rezept>();
private List<Zutaten> ingredients = new List<Zutaten>();

private void AddIngredient()
{
    var i = new Zutaten();
    ingredients.Add(i);
}

private void AddRecipe()
{
    var r = new Rezept("My Recipe", ingredients);
    ingredients = new List<Zutaten>();
    recipes.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: so should i declare the list somewhere else? because i have to use the list in my 3rd code, so i declare it globally,or what should i do?

Comment: When do you create a new Recipe?

Comment: when i click on a button, so the 3rd code is an eventhandler

Comment: wow.... that just work.. can i ask y u declare the ingredients for the 2nd time as a list?

Comment: @IwanRaflis I'm not declaring it a second time, I'm creating another list.  The first one goes to the first recipe, the second one goes to the second recipe, the third one goes to the third recipe...

Answer (score 0):

You made all instances of Rezept share the same reference to z. So once you change z, every instances' ingredient would changed too.

In the constructor of Rezept, try use:

```
this.ingredient = ingredient.Clone();
```

instead of

```
this.ingredient = ingredient;
```

That might solve your problem.

Comment: The Ingredient list is getting cleared out before the Recipe is created.  This won't help.

Comment: cant do that in c# i think.

Comment: @IwanRaflis You can indeed Clone things, although it is a protected member so you would have to expose it.

Comment: @IwanRaflis I think it would help. After Clone, it would point to other reference, so it would got influenced by others.